# Какова функция языка в данном сообщении?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Какова функция языка в следующем сообщении:

> Вход со двора. Извините за временные неудобства.

Comment: Здесь два предложения, а не одно.

Answer (score 2):

Это **коммуникативная функция**, передача информации.

Эта функция связана с тем, что язык – это средство межличностного **общения,** которое позволяет одному человеку высказать свои мысли и передать их другому, а другому, в свою очередь, понять их и отреагировать. По сути, язык возник именно для коммуникации, то есть общения, **обмена информацией**.

К **основным функциям языка** можно отнести коммуникативную, познавательную, номинативную и аккумулятивную.

http://fb.ru/article/44622/osnovnyie-funktsii-yazyika